Clarification on $A=\{a_1,a_2,...a_n\}$ by axiom
If I have a collection of objects, $a_1,a_2,..,a_n$ does a set containing them all exist, i.e $A=\{a_1,a_2,...a_n\}$,
if $n$ is finite, we can prove inductively using axiom of pairing with axiom of union:
say $n=3$, by axiom of pairing, by axiom of pairing, $\{a_1,a_2\}$ and $\{a_2,a_3\}$ exists,
then $\{ \{a_1,a_2\} , \{a_2,a_3\} \}$ exists, by axiom of union $\{ a_1,a_2,a_3 \}$ exists.
And then we can prove inductively for any natural number $n$.

Then can we say that if I have a countable collection of objects, then
a set containing them all exist? (*)

(Though I can prove for arbitrary natural number $n$
by induction, this is still a bit differently than (*))
Also for the uncountable case,
I know Dedekind cuts exist, and
$\mathbb{R}=\{\alpha \mid \alpha \text{ is Dedekind cuts} \}$,
so how do we know $\mathbb{R}$ exist? It seemed quite arbitrary,
do we need other axiom?
Also I know the collection can't be arbitrary large, take the
collection of all sets, but a set containing them does not exist.
Quite confused, clarification needed.
Many direct use of infinite intersection and  infinite union exists in textbook,like

If $\{V_λ \}_{λ \in I}$ is an arbitrary collection of open sets, then
$\cup_{λ \in I}V_λ$ is also open.


If $\{V_λ \}_{λ \in I}$ is an arbitrary collection of closed sets, then
$\cap_{λ \in I}V_λ$ is also closed.


Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $A\subset X$. The closure of $A$ is the set,
$\bar{A} := \cap \{E \subset X \mid E \text{ is closed and }A \subset E\}$.


You need the axiom of infinity to state the existence of an infinite set, I believe.

I think axiom of infinity just says $\mathbb{N}$ exist

The axiom of infinity usually says "there exists an inductive set".

You say "objects". What are "objects"? No set theory I am familiar with has "objects",  (though some have ur-elements), and pairing and union talk about sets. If you mean sets, say sets, not "objects".

You'll need to be more precise about what it means that you "have a collection of sets". "Have" is not usually a defined term in set theory, but often what we actually mean by it can be represented in the formal logic: we have proved each exists, or have defined each in a unique way, or can inductively define each from previous sets.

@aschepler that's exactly why I need clarification:(, as last 3 examples comes from the book "Basic Analysis I", you can see it only uses "an collection of sets", and I don't know what that means:(

If you have an arbitrary collection of sets $\{A_{\alpha} \mid \alpha \lt \kappa \}$, then the existence of the index means that there is a function $f$ from $\kappa$ to your collection.  Then $\operatorname {range} f$ is what you want.
I'll add that arbitrary intersections are easy using comprehension.  To take your last example, $\overline A = \{ x \in X \mid \forall E ~(E \text{ closed and } A \subseteq E \Rightarrow x \in E) \}$.  More generally, an arbitrary intersection is simply the subset of elements of any one element of the collection that is also in all other elements of the collection.
Similarly, your open set example is easy because for the statement to make sense, all of your open sets must be in a single topological space $U$.  Thus, in that case $\displaystyle \bigcup_{\lambda \in I} V_{\lambda} = \{ x \in U \mid \exists \lambda \in I ~ (x \in V_{\lambda}) \}$.

Just some commentary... maybe an addendum to your answer: I wonder if someone having these concerns would be okay with presuming $f$ is a function.  Even if that's not okay, the more general situation is the axiom schema of replacement, which gives the same result and then allows us to prove $f$ is actually a function.

Well, there is the axiom of union which states that if $V$ is a set, then there exists a set $\bigcup V$. This allows you to form the union of a family of sets. Also, there is the axiom of power set, from which you can deduce the existence of the real numbers since $\mathbb{R}_{\text{Dedekind}}\subset$$\mathcal{P}( \mathbb{Q}).$ In general, you can form any reasonable collection using the axioms of ZFC, as can be seen in any elementary axiomatic set-theory book.

If $A$ exists, then $\cup A$ exists. But does $A={a_1,a_2,...a_n}$ exist in the first place?

Well, you will need to to prove the existence of $A$. Any basic set theory book(for example, Halmos) will prove the existence of any reasonable collection that exists in mathematics.
